# Unable to set tab active after page redirect in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Unable to set tab active after page redirect in jquery

working on mvc 4 project.

I tried like following

By default when page gets redirect it make `#tab1` `active`,    I want it should be `#tab9`

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        setTimeout('setInductionTab()', 500);

    });

    function setInductionTab() {
         if ('Test' == 'Test') {
             $("#tab1").hide();
             $("#tab9").show();
             $("a").each(function () {
                 if ($(this).attr('href') == "#tab9") {
                     $(this).parent().addClass("active");
                 } else if ($(this).attr('href') == "#tab1") {
                     $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
                 }
             });
                           }  
    }
</script>
```

Which is working fine but I want to do this on ready `without setTimeout`

Comment: Are you using jQuery ui tabs?

Comment: For one thing, `('Test' != 'Test')` will never return true. What's that in your code for?

Comment: Is `tab1` made active by some javascript after page load? Or is already active in the generated HTML?

Comment: sorry wrongly edited  ;)

Comment: it is done by default in generated html

Comment: your if statement is useless if('test'=='test') this is always true

Comment: @Sora those values actually goes dynamically.. do not focus on those ..problem is i want to achieve #tab9 active without `setTimeout`